How to use BLAS in C, using gcc on Linux?
On Linux, in the file a.c, I do #include <cblas.h> and later I do cblas_sgemm(...). Compiling with
gcc -O2 -march=native -fopenmp a.c
or with
gcc -O2 -march=native -lblas -fopenmp a.c
results in "undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'", while compiling with
gcc -O2 -march=native -lcblas -fopenmp a.c
results in "cannot find -lcblas: No such file or directory". How can I make that work?

Please provide some more information, such as 1) Which CBLAS implementation is installed on your machine? Is there a libblas.a or libcblas.a library in your PATH? 2) A minimum reproducible example.

If you are using GSL's CBLAS implementation, you have to use -lgsl -lgslcblas instead. So, the answer to your question depends on which exact library you're using.

@loonatick Thank you very much. And how can I find which libraries I would like to use, if its my first time trying to use BLAS on this PopOS (Ubuntu derivative) installation? I tried searching for files, there are some libblas.a files under ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/ and ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. There are also libblas.so files in those directories. How should I link to those? I am not very familiar with gcc options.

Okay, so you're linking with libblas.a (-lblas) and including cblas.h, but ``libblas.adoes not have any function with the namecblas_sgemm.  It seems like the #includeand the library you're linking to might be different libraries. What happens if you usesgemminstead ofcblas_sgemm`? How exactly did you install your BLAS libraries?

@loonatick If I use sgemm instead of cblas_sgemm then I still get an error, although with a warning "implicit declaration of function ‘sgemm’", which I guess means that the header file cblas.h does not contain sgemm (while it contains cblas_sgemm).

@loonatick I tried to dig a bit more. I now include /usr/include/gsl/gsl_cblas.h (it contains a declaration of cblas_sgemm, I checked) and also /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ nm libgslcblas.a | grep "sgemm" outputs
'''
sgemm.o:
0000000000000000 T cblas_sgemm
'''
which, I guess, shows that it contains an implementation of cblas_sgemm. I then run gcc with -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgslcblas
but still I get an error undefined reference to cblas_sgemm'`

@loonatick Turns out, I simply should have written the source file and output -o file before all the other options when running gcc... Now it works. Sorry for that.
